# mySQL Query won't work from PHP but works in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I run an SQL query from PHP MyAdmin, it inserts the line correctly; when I run it from PHP, it does not.

I am going to provide you with the text in each; they are identical but given I might have missed something, I don't want to assume there are no differences;

IN PHP:

```
$orderSend = "SET @typeSQL := (SELECT `typeID` FROM `ArbuckleType` WHERE `typeName` = 'A la Carte');

        SET @groupSQL:= (SELECT `groupID` FROM `ArbuckleGroup` WHERE (`groupName` = 'Nigiri' AND `typeID` = @typeSQL));

        SET @itemSQL:=(SELECT `itemID` FROM `ArbuckleItem` WHERE (`itemName` = 'Salmon' AND `groupID` = @groupSQL));

        INSERT INTO `ArbuckleOrderDetails` VALUES('', '$orderID', @typeSQL,@groupSQL, @itemSQL, '$quantity', '$spicy')";
mysql_query($orderSend);
```

Now in PHP MyAdmin:

```
SET @type := (SELECT `typeID` FROM `ArbuckleType` WHERE `typeName` = 'A la Carte');# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).  

        SET @group:= (SELECT `groupID` FROM `ArbuckleGroup` WHERE (`groupName` = 'Nigiri' AND `typeID` = @type));# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

        SET @item:=(SELECT `itemID` FROM `ArbuckleItem` WHERE (`itemName` = 'Salmon' AND `groupID` = @group));# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

INSERT INTO `ArbuckleOrderDetails` VALUES('', '$orderID', @type,@group, @item, '$quantity', '$spicy')
```

NOTE: I ran the PHP query WITHOUT the SET calls (the 3 lines setting the variables) and it worked; but I can't figure out where there is wrong syntax in those lines. Also ran mysql_error and it states that there is a syntax error - then asks me to look at the manual. Very helpful, mysql.

Comment: I wouldn't be using the mysql_* functions. They are deprecated and for good reasons. Read more at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mysql_query() cannot execute multiple queries at once.

Two solutions:

1. Use multiple mysql_query lines
2. use mysqli with [multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Your code, rewriten to multiple mysql_query lines:

```
mysql_query("SET @typeSQL := (SELECT `typeID` FROM `ArbuckleType` WHERE `typeName` = 'A la Carte')");
mysql_query("SET @groupSQL:= (SELECT `groupID` FROM `ArbuckleGroup` WHERE (`groupName` = 'Nigiri' AND `typeID` = @typeSQL))");
mysql_query("SET @itemSQL:=(SELECT `itemID` FROM `ArbuckleItem` WHERE (`itemName` = 'Salmon' AND `groupID` = @groupSQL))");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ArbuckleOrderDetails` VALUES('', '$orderID', @typeSQL,@groupSQL, @itemSQL, '$quantity', '$spicy')");
```

Comment: Hi Maris, I was initially going to do multiple queries but then thought: doesn't doing multiple queries slow down the process? I will have a user waiting for a confirmation the order has gone through (as you can see the script involves a menu) and so I thought running everything in a single Mysql query would be quicker; am I misunderstanding how MySQL works?

Comment: Of course, single group of queries will be a bit faster. You still tried to run many queries but in one request. I would rewrite your queries in to one single query. Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0):

You have following options:

1. Use multiple queries to retrieve values and and make final query.
2. Use mysqli_query
3. Make a stored procedure and call it. (Recommended, then you need not worry about escape characters)